# Compiled Jruby application Instance variable error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby, jrubyonrails, warbler

**How do I use instance variable in jruby compiled application?**

Here is where the instace variable is used

```
def index
  @samaple = ["It's works"]
  render json: @samaple
end
```

It's shows the following error when deployed:

```
Internal Server Error (500)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8080/blog1/

/opt/tomcat/webapps/unbxd_jruby/WEB-INF/app/controllers/webapp/WEB-INF/app/controllers/home_controller.class is not compiled Ruby; use java_import to load normal classes...
```

The compiled code for jruby application showing error where the instace variables are used